# simulation of lpt interface

Tags: serial

If I get usb to parallel convereter,can I use the same address  (378H) that are used in lpt interface for data port in this converter ? If yes ,what is the dll library should be used?

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design. Question should be closed.

Comment: A USB printer adapter will let you print things, but it is an entirely different implementation than the original IBM PC printer port. If you try to address port 378h, it doesn't matter if there's this USB thingy sitting over there, if there's no hardware decoding port 378h, nothing will happen when you write to port 378h. and fwiw, the question is basically off topic here.

Comment: This topic should be asked at stackoverflow programming site.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, you can't just use 378h, because the USB device works just as a printer port. Usually it's just for printing and doesn't support full range of original LPT features. But you can buy a real 378h parallel port on a PCI card.

Look here: [Writing to a Parallel to USB convertor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24265/writing-to-a-parallel-to-usb-convertor)

Also note that it is not possible to directly write to 378h in Windows 2000 and later, because direct access to hardware devices is prohibited. This policy is enforced by the CPU and if you try to write to 378h you get something like an access violation exception.